# We should not be pasting definitions from online dictionaries into answers when their terms of service prohibit such use

Tags: discussion, copyrights

Some online dictionaries prohibit such copying of their content. Some examples below (not meant to be an exhaustive list, and any bolding for emphasis is mine) :

First, from the Stack Exchange terms of service:

> "...any and all content...that you provide to the public Network ...is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Overflow on a worldwide, royalty-free, non-exclusive basis pursuant to Creative Commons licensing terms (CC BY-SA 4.0), and you grant Stack Overflow the perpetual and irrevocable right and license to access, use, process, copy, distribute, export, display and **to commercially exploit** such Subscriber Content, even if such Subscriber Content has been contributed and subsequently removed by you..."

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/terms-and-conditions):

> Your use of the Site and its contents grants no rights to You in relation to Our intellectual property rights including, without limitation, trade marks, logos, graphics, photographs, animations, videos and **text** or the intellectual property of third parties in the Site and its contents. **None of the Content or User Content may be downloaded, copied, reproduced, republished, edited, posted, transmitted, stored, commercially exploited, sold or distributed without the prior written permission of the copyright holder.** Subject to the above You may download insubstantial extracts from the Site on any single computer **for personal, non-commercial home use only**, provided that no more than one copy of any information is made and all copyright and proprietary notices are kept intact.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/i/terms-of-use):

> you may "reproduce... content...**only for your personal, non-commercial use**. If you are a teacher, scholar or student, you may copy reasonable portions of the content...for lesson plans, interactive whiteboards, reports, dissertations, presentations, school newspapers and for similar nonprofit educational purposes to the extent permitted by applicable law. ... If you want to reproduce or use content ... **in any manner other than as described above**, including for purposes of developing or training AI or to conduct computer analysis, you will need Merriam-Webster's permission."

[Longman](https://www.pearson.com/en-us/legal-information/terms-of-use.html)

> The reproduction, redistribution, modification or publication of any part of the Services without the express written consent of Pearson and/or its licensors is strictly prohibited.

Comment: Why limit this question about pasting definitions to copyright considerations? I fear that the question, in its current form, will provoke amateurish attempts at interpreting the law, while there is a much broader issue behind it (that we are likely to be more competent to discuss): when is it good, useful, helpful, illuminating to quote dictionary definitions on this site (regardless of the legality of doing so)? Many contributors to this site seem to think of quoting dictionaries as some sort of a ritual that must be performed in every answer, even when it doesn't add anything to it.

Comment: @jsw29 Yes, there are other ways, besides upvotes, to give a questioner confidence that an answer isn't something concocted by a fevered brain.  Google Books previews, for example, show words in the wild.  If a dozen or more books use a word in the way the answer says it can be used, that should suffice.  No dictionary cut-and-paste required.  We should assume that everyone who comes here knows how to use a dictionary.

Comment: If you start pulling at that thread, all of our SE sites will unravel.

Comment: @Robusto:  The moth-holes of link rot are clearly better than having the sweater unravel, no? Besides, there may be technology solutions to tracking down the current location of the content and replacing the rotted link *in situ*.

Comment: @herisson I thought some of your answers were quite intelligent. But that remark  is foolish. Surely you understand the difference between "Content" and the Terms of Service that govern use of such content.

Answer (score 14):

The rule is to assume [fair use](https://copyright.psu.edu/copyright-basics/fair-use), which allows users to (legally) post quotes without permission from the copyright holder. If it's not really fair use (and I think it is, as part of a scholarly work), the copyright holder (or their agent) can submit a DMCA claim through the [Contact Us](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/contact) form, which is then handled by staff. We—as moderators and not copyright lawyers and especially not lawyers representing either "side"—don't touch copyright stuff (only plagiarism—a matter of academic integrity, not law).

Comment: Your understanding of fair use is yours. There are other opinions: https://www.findlaw.com/smallbusiness/business-operations/is-it-ok-to-copy-material-from-a-website.html or https://guides.nyu.edu/fairuse

Comment: I am not asking moderators to take any action.  I am advising against doing it, and my followup would be certainly not to REQUIRE such copying.

Comment: @TimR And that's exactly why the lawyers SE are paying should be the ones to determine what looks like fair use and what should be removed—not you or me. On the other hand, my understanding of SE policy is exactly [what staff have been telling us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/113563/323179) for over a decade.

Comment: I am not asking for it to be removed. That's up to SE. I'm advising against it (people can do want they want) but I'm certainly against REQUIRING answers to do it.  https://www.copyrightlaws.com/sharing-republishing-online-content/

Comment: @TimR But it's not up to you to give advice, and your question should be a question along the lines of "Should we...?" You can then give your opinion in an answer.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I'm not giving SE advice.  I'm addressing the forum  members, in whose forum a "rule" has been devised that certain kinds of answers must cut and paste a dictionary entry (not simply link to it) or risk having the answer be deleted.

Comment: Side note: since SE is a commercial enterprise, it cannot IMO claim "nonprofit scholarly/educational" status.  But let's leave that as a side note since the line between higher education and for-profit corporation is becoming blurred, and I'd rather not go down that rabbit hole. The main gist of my post is to advise against having a rule that requires cutting and pasting of dictionary entries.

Comment: @TimR I was directly addressing your comment "I'm advising against it," which I didn't think was addressed to SE.

Comment: @AndrewLeach  It was addressed to anyone and everyone here who thinks pasting  dictionary entries verbatim, even from dictionaries whose terms expressly forbid it, is something this forum should be *requiring* of people when they are answering certain kinds of questions.

Comment: @TimR: "Terms of service" are not binding on anyone who hasn't signed them. Visiting a website is not signing a contract. The problem is link rot: if you only link and not quote, your answer will become useless once the site changes its structure, which the commercial sites always do.

Comment: Some terms of service have words to this effect:  *By continuing to use this website you are agreeing to these terms*.  Are you certain those words are legally vapid?

Comment: @TimR: Yes, absolutely! Imagine if some website could make you 'accept' any terms it liked, just by sending the page content to your computer.

Comment: @Cerberus-ReinstateMonica You seem not to understand the implications of the word **continuing**.  You cannot *continue to use* something you have never used.  The clearly entailed meaning is that if you've visited the site at least once, and want to use it again, you must abide by the terms. It's possible you've just downloaded the Terms and are reading them offline, but for most people they're reading the words *while visiting*.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is link rot: if you only link and not quote, your answer will become useless once the site changes its structure, which the commercial sites always do.

"Terms of service" are not binding on anyone who hasn't signed them. Visiting a website is not signing a contract.

Comment: Easily addressed.  "See Merriam-Webster *polysemy*, n."

Comment: These resources are telling users not to repost their content. If they are able to exist only by virtue of ad revenue, not to send visitors their way is to undermine them, and they may cease to exist or become paywalled.  If the link may rot, don't include it. But don't steal their content and make it so that no one needs to visit their website to get it.

Comment: @TimR: It doesn't matter what they "tell" a visitor (not to mention that nobody ever sees such a message). They choose to send their content to any computer who visits their web address; that is their own choice. Receiving the freely sent content has nothing whatsoever to do with crime (theft), and I think that is a rather infelicitous comparison.

Comment: The misappropriation of intellectual property is "theft".

Comment: @TimR: It is not. Besides, so-called intellectual property is inalienable, one cannot appropriate it by copying text. And of course there is fair use. And all the other things that are mentioned here.

Comment: I am willing to leave all of you to your individual opinions and to take your own actions as you see fit when it comes to reposting content from other websites.  Just don't require other people to copy and paste such content if they want to participate on this site.   You don't consider my stance a fair-minded one?  I should be able to refer to that content without having to repost it.

Comment: @TimR: Is it really a good answer if it doesn't contain the information? It is like writing an academic article but putting the real information in an end note. P.S. I really cannot fathom why anyone would pity a big company and its profits. It is not a person. It is not sympathetic.

Comment: The position can be principled and not based on pity. And/or it could be enlightened self-interest, not wanting to see these sites pay-walled.

Comment: As for whether it's a good answer...   I think the whole point of an upvoting/downvoting site is *corroboration*, not reward.  If the site upvotes an answer, it's corroboration that it is a "right" answer.  If they downvote it, it's an indicator that it's a wrong answer. I don't think stuff that is common knowledge should require cutting and pasting from "an authority" and an  authority could be *referenced* when needed. There's no need to paste in content.

Comment: @TimR: The goal of Stack Exchange is to be a compendium of knowledge. Rotten links are in opposition to that goal. Empty answers which contain no knowledge but only a reference aren't very valuable either.

Comment: You seem to be more interested in polemic than in discussion. I said give an answer and *reference* an authority to back it up, not simply point at some external site.

Comment: @TimR: If there is a substantial answer that carries its own value, then, OK. But I thought the answers we were talking about here were the ones where someone merely posts one or two sentences of his own with a reference. In any case, it is always better to add a quotation if you refer to something.

Answer (score 3):

I certainly agree that we should not knowingly violate the terms of service of a website. However, I don't agree that dictionary sites forbid this type of usage.

For example on The Free Dictionary site (which is a aggregation of several dictionaries) [the page with several definitions of the word fleecy](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/fleecy) links to [a page with proper citations](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/cite.aspx?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.thefreedictionary.com%2Ffleecy&word=fleecy&sources=hm,hc_dict,rHouse,wn,hc_thes,hm_thes,hc_En_Es,hc_En_Fr,hc_En_De,hc_En_It,kdict) for each source of each definition listed in APA, Chicago, MLA and PLOS styles.

I don't know why they would provide that if the expectation is that someone could not use a definition to support an answer, so long as it includes the proper citation. Their [terms of service](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/about.htm) states:

> 4. No Duplication or Redistribution: Material contained in the Content may not be duplicated or redistributed without the prior written consent of Farlex, except that one print copy of search output is permitted for use within Your home, and that search output may be stored temporarily in electronic media for editing or reformatting and subsequent printing of one print copy of search output for internal use.

Merriam-Webster [provides citation advice under their "help" section](https://www.merriam-webster.com/help/citing-the-dictionary):

> Here are three ways you might cite the entry for hacker in the Merriam-Webster Online Dictionary, if you accessed it on May 8, 2011.
> "hacker." Merriam-Webster.com. 2011. https://www.merriam-webster.com
> (8 May 2011).
>
> MLA Style:
>
> "hacker." Merriam-Webster.com. Merriam-Webster, 2011.
>
> Web. 8 May 2011.
>
> APA Style:
>
> hacker. 2011. In Merriam-Webster.com.
>
> Retrieved May 8, 2011, from
> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hacker

I don't know why they would bother if their expectation was that their terms of service would restrict us from quoting their dictionary, so I am comfortable with including properly attributed quotes in answers unless the site makes it explicitly clear that is not allowed (like they have done with scraping the site for the purposes of training an AI model).

Comment: Farlex authorizes home use. Their citation is a hyperlink not a copy-paste. M-W again has you linking to their site, not pasting in their content into another website.  That is a critical distinction that needs to be understood.  The supposed problem of "link rot" has been used as a justification for copy-paste. It is not a justification, especially when the dictionary uses permalinks.

Comment: @TimR It's a citation, not a link back to their site, otherwise it would not include the date it was retrieved from that site. If you're just pasting a link, you aren't retrieving anything. Even M-W expects that their definitions will be quoted, and so the date it was retrieved is important just in case it was changed in the meantime.

Comment: M-W are not authorizing copy-paste of an entire entry into a website. They are showing how you should cite the definition if your use is one of the explicitly authorized uses.  The conclusion you've drawn from their advice on proper citation format is unwarranted.

Comment: @TimR "Use of Content: You may display, reproduce, print or download content, including images, from the Services only for your personal, non-commercial use." My answers are personal and non-commercial. I quote and attribute properly to separate the content I'm contributing from content I do not own the license to. I am not concerned at all that M-W's legal department is going to send me a cease and desist.

Comment: Your answers are not  "only for your personal" use.  Nothing reposted to a public site meets that standard. And when the public site's terms of use say you're giving them the right to exploit commercially what you have posted, things get very messy indeed. You lack of concern is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, you may be right. Practically, legal questions are decided in court, and it's unlikely anyone will be taken to court over this. Morally, each user can make a personal judgement whether it is equivalent to theft to copy a portion of a dictionary entry when giving an answer on this site.

As Laurel said, copyright law in the United States has the exception of fair use.

In terms of contract law, as far as I can tell you are correct that such terms of service may theoretically be enforceable against users of these sites. Abruzzi 2009 discusses this and raises concerns about it, but notes

> to this point the law reporters have recorded very few instances in which content purveyors have litigated to hold users to the terms of website TOU - and only one case in which the content purveyor sued over a term that restricted fair use of a content.

(page 138, "[Copyright, Free Expression, and the Enforceability of Personal Use-Only and Other Use-Restrictive Online Terms of Use](https://digitalcommons.law.scu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1496&context=chtlj)", by Bradley F. Abruzzi, 2009)

However, Abruzzi also discusses some potential legal defenses, so the law here may not be completely one-sided.  (Also, I don't know how this field has evolved since 2009.)

In addition, my understanding is that (unlike copyright infringement) breach of contract as a cause of action would only allow for civil, not criminal remedies, and it's hard to imagine that the damages involved in the case of users of this website would be sufficient to motivate any legal proceedings. (I'm not sure, but I also suspect that it would be harder to get punitive damages for breach of contract than it is to get statutory damages for copyright infringement.)

Setting aside questions of law, an answer that consists solely of a verbatim quotation of a dictionary entry is never ideal: it's better to give answers that include useful explanations in your own words.